# How can I assign jQuery variable to Smarty template function

Tags: jquery, smarty

I have one html button that onclick calls function "checkInfo($smartyVariable)"

```
<button onclick="return checkInfo({$smartyVariable})">Check Info</button>

 function checkInfo($SmartyID){
    {assign var="campaignInfoMandrill" value=EmailCampaign_View::getMandrill($SmartyId)} //can't assign this "$SmartyId" inside jquery funciton    
        alert({$SmartyId});//displays correct the id
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify meaning of "assign jquery variable" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want Smarty variable to be printed properly, you are missing curly brackets:

```
<button onclick="return checkInfo({$smartyVariable})">Check Info</button>
```

**EDIT 1:**

In case you're trying to run `function checkInfo($SmartyID)` from inside of the template - it was disabled by default since Smarty 3.0. You must create a Smarty plugin using you're code or assign to template directly using PHP.

**EDIT 2:**

As I can see now, you're trying to run JavaScript code from PHP code? It will not work as this.

Comment: No that was a typo i have the curly brackets, i will edit now the question on that part. I have a problem to add parameter of the jquery to {assign var="campaignInfoMandrill" value=EmailCampaign_View::getMandrill($SmartyId)} //can't assign this "$SmartyId" inside jquery funciton

        alert({$SmartyId}) "HERE"         I can run function checkInfo($martyID) but inside that function i can not add the "$smartyID" variable

Comment: You can not do this. Server side part knows nothing about what happens in the browser (jQuery). What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a foreach loop that have some campaignID now for each specific campaign i want to check on mandrill to see if i have information about that specific campaign when i click the button

Comment: Then you need to use AJAX call to the server that would return data properly, calling the function you're trying to use. Instead of alert you would use `return $SmartyId` and later parse it the way you need.